# How to solve $dy/dt + y \sqrt{t} \sin (t) = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do we solve 
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} + y \sqrt{t} \sin (t) = 0?
$$

I cannot evaluate the integral
$$
\int \sqrt{t} \sin t dt.
$$

Comment: I don't think it can be expressed in a nice (simple) way.

Comment: Series expansion of sin(t), then term-by-term integration may help. I don't know the domain of values for t though.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:$$\large{\frac{dy}{dt} + y \sqrt{t} \sin (t) = 0\to \color{green}{y(t)=e^{\int \limits_0^t\sqrt u \sin (u)du}+c}}$$
$$\large{\int \limits_0^t\sqrt u \sin (u)du.=\int \limits_0^t\sqrt u \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nu^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}du=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int \limits_0^t\sqrt u \frac{(-1)^nu^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}du}$$

$$\large{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int \limits_0^t\frac{(-1)^nu^{2n+\dfrac32}}{(2n+1)!}du}=\large{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nt^{2n+\dfrac52}}{(2n+\dfrac52)(2n+1)!}}$$

Comment: Hm... Is it supposed to be this complex? This question is like intro ode problem (actually it is the Exercise 1.2.2 in Braun's DE textbook) but then it requires some measure theory..?

Comment: @julypraise I don't know that book, but if it's an introductory book then the idea is probably to just take the indefinite integral.

Comment: Oh right... Why I didn't think of that..

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives this closed form integral: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28sqrt%28t%29sin%28t%29%29 , which includes complex Fresnel integral.